# Script to delete folder with time condition

Tags: command-line, batch, file-management

I wrote a command to create a folder named with day's date and copy some file and folders to it.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do set wday=%%a&set month=%%b&set day=%%c&set year=%%d
set tmpname="%day%_%month%_%year%"
mkdir %tmpname%

xcopy /e \\192.168.0.11\bkup x:%tmpname%
```

Now, I want a command line that will delete folders that are 10 days old. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve using batch files. Think about what happens when the month changes. Getting the date 10 days ago is not simple. [how to get yesterday's date in a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11891335) will give you some ideas (and show you how difficult it is).

Comment: [How to delete Folders and Files older than 10 day ?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f983d0da-d9da-400f-930b-9e3af9ba422f/how-to-delete-folders-and-files-older-than-10-day-?forum=winserverfiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of two utilities to achieve what you want:

[DelAge32](http://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm): `delage32 x:\*.* 10 /recurse`

[RmEmpty](http://www.filegate.net/utiln/utilwin/): `rmempty x:\`

Similar to you, I use both tools to delete system logs older than 10 days.

This is all performed via command line in a `.bat` file. Tested in Windows XP, 7, and 10.

Comment: tanks for your answer. but its not working.
the .bat say:


'delage32' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'rmempty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
and my batch cammand is:
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do set wday=%%a&set month=%%b&set day=%%c&set year=%%d
set tmpname="%day%_%month%_%year%"
mkdir %tmpname%

REM ===== command #2

Robocopy "\\192.168.0.11\BKUP" "x:%tmpname%" /e

delage32 x:\*.* 10 /recurse

rmempty  x:\

where i do wrong???

Comment: My links to the files are in the answer.you must download the files

Comment: ok
thanks man
im very tanksfull for your answers
1 more question
how to use this files
copy this .exe files to what distanition???

Comment: Exe has to be in a directory that is part of your path. I put mine is c:\apps and put that directory in my path. Search environmental variables in Google

Comment: sorry for my dumbness
. can you type an example??

Comment: is it right???
                                               
Robocopy "\\192.168.0.11\BKUP" "x:%tmpname%" /e

delage32 x:\*.* 10 /recurse

rmempty  x:\

Comment: that worked. thanks alot. no body on the earth know that.